# insertar elemento menu.html en todas mis paginas html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas quiero importar mi `menu.html` en todas las paginas de mi web.

este es mi `menu.html`

```
<html>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>    
</html>
```

este es mi `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Index</title>
    <!-- IMPORTS.. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- SCRIPTS PERSONALIZADOS -->
    <script src="../js/cargar_menu.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="menu" class="col">
                    <script>insert_menu();</script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur nobis dolores assumenda minus dolorum cor  rupti 
                quia veritatis dolor ipsa nesciunt distinctio, et autem corporis nostrum quas, non consequatur odio eveniet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

este es mi archivo `cargar_menu.js` que se encarga de implantar el menú en las paginas html que yo le indique con **jQuery**.

```
$(function insert_menu(){
    $("#menu").load("../componentes/menu.html"); 
    return this;
  });
```

Mi problema es que no me lo inserta

**Codigo de error:**

> TypeError: $(...).load is not a function

---

He añadido esto :        `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` en el **fichero.html** y ahora me arroja el siguiente **error**: `Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en file:... (razón: la solicitud CORS no es http).`

Comment: y la función `insert_menu` donde la llamas?

Comment: ya lo he actualizado @JuanSalvadorPortugal , esta en el fichero **index.html**

Answer (score 2):

La versión slim de jQuery [no incluye la función load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery).

Para poder usarla, carga la versión completa:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

Edit: estos son algunos errores que veo

- Si pones `src` en un script lo que haya dentro es ignorado. Cambia lo siguiente:

`<script src="../js/cargar_menu.js"></script>`

- Dentro del jQuery document ready va una función anónima:

```
$(function () {
    $("#menu").load("../componentes/menu.html"); 
});
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, me devuelve este error con eso puesto =TypeError: g is undefined[Saber más] util.js:55:2

  `  <anonymous> util.js:55 <anonymous> bootstrap.min.js:6 <anonymous> bootstrap.min.js:6 `

Comment: Editado, mira a ver si eso te sirve, debería funcionar. No te olvides también de quitar jquery-1.10.2.js. Por cierto, el error que has escrito podría ser porque cargas bootstrap.min.js antes que jquery-3.3.1.min.js.

Comment: Ya lo he editado, pero ahora me dice que no me reconoce la llamada el metodo , me arroja el siguiente error  `ReferenceError: insert_menu is not defined[Saber más]`

Comment: No deberías estar usando el nombre `insert_menu`. No necesitas la función porque el `$("#menu").load(...)` se ejecuta cuando cargas la página. Quizás la estás llamando desde otro archivo?

Comment: A ver, tengo 3 ficheros **fichero 1=menu.html** solo contiene el `nav` del menu. **fichero 2=index.html** simplemente es la pagina principal. **fichero 3=cargar_menu.js** esto es lo que carga mi menu. Asi que el flujo es el siguiente : **index** llama a **cargar_menu** y este llama al **nav_menu**

Comment: Has cambiado esto: `<script src="../js/cargar_menu.js"></script>`? Si no, ya no sé qué te puede estar dando ese error

Comment: eso lo pongo en el head no? y con el div con id=menu ya lo debe detectar no ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90496/discussion-between-david-silva-and-josanangel).

Answer (score 0):

Usando [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Web_Components), es posible crear un componente personalizado que te permita hacer lo que buscas:

Ejemplo:

```
customElements.define('yus-html',
            class extends HTMLElement {
                constructor() {
                    super();
                }
                connectedCallback() {
                    console.log(this.getAttribute("src"));
                    fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))
                        .then(r => r.text())
                        .then(t => {
                            let parser = new DOMParser();
                            let html = parser.parseFromString(t, "text/html");
                            this.innerHTML = html.body.innerHTML;
                        }).catch(e => console.error(e));

                }
            });
```

Este código lo puedes colocar en un archivo separado o dentro del HTML padre.

Luego para usarlo solo debes hacer:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="menu" class="col">
                    <yus-html src="Menu.html"></yus-html>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <yus-html src="OtroHtml.html"></yus-html>
        </div>

        <yus-html src="OtroOtroHtml.html"></yus-html>
    </div>
</body>
```