# Insertar un fragmento html dentro de un documento html con HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy intenado meter el documento **menu.html** dentro de mi **index.html**

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Index</title>
    <!-- IMPORTS.. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- SCRIPTS PERSONALIZADOS -->


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur nobis dolores assumenda minus dolorum
                cor rupti
                quia veritatis dolor ipsa nesciunt distinctio, et autem corporis nostrum quas, non consequatur odio
                eveniet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**menu.html**

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="../paginas/index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Lo he intentado con el iframe, pero no me lo hace bien y ni siquiera me detecta el bootstrap en el menu.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [insertar elemento menu.html en todas mis paginas html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/242409/insertar-elemento-menu-html-en-todas-mis-paginas-html)

Comment: Por clarificar, lo que @josanangel pretendía era insertar un trozo de HTML dentro de otro sin usar jQuery. Pero no tiene un servidor web (sería cargar archivos locales `file:///`), por lo que yo creo que no se puede conseguir.

Comment: A qué te refieres con _el iframe no me lo hace bien_? Justo ahora estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Bootstrap y en el HTML llamo otro doc `.html` sin ningún problema con la etiqueta iframe. Muéstranos en tu código cómo lo estás haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con JavaScript de esta manera:

```js
ponAquiElMenu.innerHTML = `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="../paginas/index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>`;
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" id="ponAquiElMenu">

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur nobis dolores assumenda minus dolorum
                cor rupti
                quia veritatis dolor ipsa nesciunt distinctio, et autem corporis nostrum quas, non consequatur odio
                eveniet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

y si usas php ?

```
<?php include 'menu.html';  ?>
```

solo que tu archivo index.html lo cambias a index.php

o la otra opción es que en el archivo menu.html tambien pongas los estilos de bootstrap

Comment: y si no es PHP lo que usa?

Comment: En el menu.html  tambien use bootstrap y el iframe lo haga responsive

Comment: Es incorrecto duplicar las hojas de estilo si vas a utilizar `include` de PHP. Las hojas de estilo únicas deben ir solamente en el primer documento .php que se llame dentro del archivo

Comment: Lo se, pero no esta usando php

Answer (score 0):

Yo hago cosas similares en PHP y cuando necesito que un DIV tenga datos (o una estructura) desde que se carga el html uso lo siguiente

Estructura HTML que carga el contenido

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> #Este script debe ir si o si
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" id="menu">
            El texto introductorio
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
   </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#menu" ).load( "directorio/archivo.html", function() {});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Contenido a mostrar (en este caso, seria archivo.html)

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="../paginas/index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

De esa forma puedes crear el componente .html y usarlo desde donde quieras con la instrucción $("#elemento").load().

Espero te sirva